# How do you find the limit as $x$ approaches $0$ of the product of $1/x$ and a variable bound definite integral?

Tags: calculus, limits, definite-integrals

What approach should I take to evaluate the following limit of the general form: Find the limit of...

$\displaystyle\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac1x\int_2^{4x^2+7x}\sqrt{1+5w+w^2}\;\mathrm d w$

My scope of knowledge includes $u-$substitution and the First and Second Fundamental theories of calculus. However, up to this point, I have only encountered integral problems that are not being multiplied by another function ( $1/x$ in this case), also seeing a limit appended to the front of the integral is novel to me as well. The experience I have with FTC$1$ is solving for a derivative, and with FTC$2$ evaluating an area by using $F(a)-F(b)$. So I have no reference on how to approach problems of this type.

Comment: I think $dw$ is missing...

Comment: The integral is just a (complicated) function of $x$. What happens to it as $x$ approaches $0$?

Comment: When i look at 1/x, if x is approach zero, wouldn't the expression (1/x) become infinity ?

Comment: I suspect that actually the limit the original poster wants to calculate is the following one: $$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac1x\int_0^{4x^2+7x}\sqrt{1+5w+w^2}\;\mathrm d w$$ Is my suspect unfounded?

Comment: Yes, the $1/x$ goes to infinity. Now you have to deal with the integral, which is also "inside" the limit too. I'm assuming you could handle this if, instead of that integral, you had $x^2$, $\sqrt x$, or $\sin(x)$.

Comment: To be honest, the actual question that I have to evaluate is different from the one I posted, the reason being is for integrity purposes (ie to avoid cheating). So I created a general problem that has the exact form of the one I am working on. Nonetheless, the part of the question that is confusing me, is the request fora] limit for a product of function and a variable bound definite integral. So If I have somehow used an inappropriate lower bound for the integral this was my novice error.

Comment: So, even though it looks like the same form to you, I'm guessing they actually behave differently, and resolving this question might not resolve the original one. Nonetheless, I think your brain just shut down from seeing an integral in this context, and you should be able to answer this. So, what happens to that integral as x goes to zero?

Comment: I'm following you trade of thought Jonathan, you are really helping me to think through this question, I am trying to think of this expression as one function , lets say g(x). Then  g(x) has two component function (1/x) and the definite integral part. I assume that the independent variable of the integral is (4x^2 + 7x). Should I say that the interval of the integral function is [2, 4x^2+7x]? Then solve for delta x and the sample point xi* , to compute the area of the integral using a Reiman sum?

Comment: The lower bound of the integral should be $0$ instead of $2$, or else the limit does not exist (numerator goes to a nonzero number, denominator goes to $\pm \infty$ -- one-sided limits don't agree). With this correction in place, recognize the limit as the limit of a difference quotient $$\frac{F(x)-F(0)}{x-0}$$with $F(x) = \int_0^{4x^2+7x}...$. Or recognize what you have as an actual fraction and apply L'Hospital.

Comment: By "fraction" in my last comment I mean that the numerator is the integral and the denominator is $x$.

Comment: If there was a Topic that I could review for further insight, what would you guys recommend

Comment: What's probably new to you here is thinking of the integral as a function of its limits of integration. The "big hammer" relating to this is the "Liebniz Integral Rule". You could go check out that, though I just glanced at the Wikipedia article, and it's presented in it's most general form, so I'm worried it might be impenetrable. But maybe take a stab at that?

Comment: *sigh* The LIR covers two things: differentiating the function being integrated, and what to do when the limits of integration are functions of some variable.  You're dealing with the second part, but all the search results concentrate on the first part. Sorry, I couldn't find a good link for your question.

Comment: @IvoTerek - Can you just make that an answer? I'd gladly up vote it.

Comment: @Jonathan Sure, no problem. OP: if there's anything unclear, just let me know and I'll elaborate a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

First, the lower bound of the integral should be $0$ instead of $2$, or else the limit does not exist (numerator goes to a nonzero number, denominator goes to $\pm \infty$ -- one-sided limits don't agree).

With this correction in place, recognize the limit as the limit of a difference quotient $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x}\int_0^{4x^2+7x} \sqrt{1+5w+w^2}\,{\rm d}w = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{F(x)-F(0)}{x-0} = F'(0),$$with $$F(x) = \int_0^{4x^2+7x} \sqrt{1+5w+w^2}\,{\rm d}w.$$Alternatively, you may recognize that$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x}\int_0^{4x^2+7x} \sqrt{1+5w+w^2}\,{\rm d}w = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\int_0^{4x^2+7x} \sqrt{1+5w+w^2}\,{\rm d}w}{x}$$and apply L'Hospital's rule (with the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and the chain rule to deal with the numerator).